# Django template: Embed css from file

Tags: python, django, templates, include, embed

I'm working on an email template, therefor I would like to embed a css file

```
<head>
   <style>{{ embed 'css/TEST.css' content here }}</style>
</head>
```

instead of linking it

```
<head>
   <link href="{% static 'css/TEST.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [django-compressor](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package. It will add `{% compress %}` template tag that can join together bunch of JS or CSS files (or inlined code) and put it into template as new, big file or inlined code. For example to inline one CSS file, you can use:

```
{% compress css inline %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/TEST.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endcompress %}
```

You can add more CSS files into one compress tag, they will be concatenated  together and wrapped into one `<style>`tag.

Check [usage examples](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#examples) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could use `include`

```
<style>{% include "/static/css/style.css" %}</style>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include

But it might be better to load the contents of the css file in your view, and put it in the context of your view to send it to the template

Answer (score 1):

On solution would be the use of include:

```
<head>
    <style>{% include "../static/css/TEST.css" %}</style>
</head>
```

But it is kind of messy!
You have to place a copy or link to your css-file in your templates directory. Or you use a hardcoded link as above, which may break in production.