# Inline CSS file in django template

Tags: css, django, performance, pagespeed

It is possible to inline an above-the-fold/critical css file in a django template ?

I was thinking of something like:

`<style>{% inline "css/home.above.css" %}</style>`

Which would result in:

`<style>html {...} body {...} {content of the css file}</style>`

But I haven't found any ressources in that regards.

Comment: Answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607083/django-template-embed-css-from-file) say that you can use `{% include %}` tag. I haven't tried it, though. Another way I can think of is you can read/open the css file in your views and put it in your template context.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon my comment, this is how you can pass your CSS file to your template context.

```
def my_view(request):
    with open('../path/to/style.css') as infile:
        css = infile.read()
        # if you want to remove newlines, uncomment the next line
        # css = css.replace('\n', '')
        # if you want to remove tabs, uncomment the next line
        # css = css.replace('\t, '')

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'css': css})
```

Then, in your template, you can use `{{ css }}` to access the whole CSS file.

---

**NOTE:** Instead of manually removing newlines and tabs from CSS, I think it's better to use a CSS compressor. For example, if you're using 4 spaces instead of tabs, then those extra spaces won't be stripped.

This library seems good - [csscompressor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csscompressor/).

Comment: Thanks. I will try to inline with django-compressor.